# Integrator Opamp offset cancellation feature

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, sensor, integrator

I am trying to build a simple integrator circuit but there are some problems. I want to eliminate offset voltage in integrator. As shown in schematic, adding a feedback circuit oscillation was occurred in simulation. How can I add an offset adjustment to this circuit?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Adding the feedback turns your integrator into something that isn't an integrator.

Comment: The first thing would be to run an AC analysis on your 'plant' and see what kind of response it has.

Comment: Just to be clear, what offset voltage are you talking about?  Input or Output??

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be feeding back the output of the integrator to eliminate an offset, this will change the AC response of the integrator, and introduce addtional poles in the feedback loop which will give you a two pole system that resonates.

You may want to try an integrator scheme like the one below, by using an inverting integrator (you may have to use another opamp to invert the signal again depending on your application, you may also not want to use a high pass filter like in the example below, but the low pass filter like you used above). By using an inverting integrator the DC offset can be applied to the V+ pin by using a potentiometer (the 50k resistors below).

[image]
[Op amp integrator output has DC offset even when a coupling capacitor is used](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/360931/op-amp-integrator-output-has-dc-offset-even-when-a-coupling-capacitor-is-used)